# matlab filter execution time

Tags: matlab, filter, parallel-processing

I need to filter 6 signals with 60000000 samples in each. So data are saved in matrix data(60000000,6). There are several aproaches how to do that:

```
data=randn(60000000,6);
b=ones(1,1000)/1000;

tic
R=filter(b,1,data);
toc

tic
for i=1:6
    R2(:,i)=filter(b,1,data(:,i));
end
toc

tic
parfor i=1:6
    R2(:,i)=filter(b,1,data(:,i));
end
toc
```

By documentation it is recommanded to use 1st form as the fastest one, but in my case it is the slowest.

```
Elapsed time is 172.235919 seconds.
Elapsed time is 45.354810 seconds.
Elapsed time is 59.250638 seconds.
```

In process explorer 1st form use only 1 thread of CPU. By documentation it should run on multiple threads in default. Have you experienced same problem?

Comment: can you specify the version of your Matlab?

Comment: R2016a - academic use